# Displaying an image with alpha channel on OSX

Tags: image, macos, alpha

I am trying to display a 32bit, 4 channeled image in my window. The fourth channel in the image is an alpha channel. As an experiment, I create a completely Red image, where each pixel has the RGB value: 255,0,0. For each pixel I also add an alpha value of 204.

What I expected to see was a completely Red image with some transparency, but what I see instead is a completely opaque image with the values altered.

Expected Output:
[image]

Current output:
[image]

The code I am using:

```
NSRect windowRect = {0,0,200,200};

m_NSWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

[m_NSWindow setTitle:@"overlayWindow"];

[m_NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

g_imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,200,200)];

[m_NSWindow.contentView addSubview:g_imageView];



[m_NSWindow setOpaque:NO];

[m_NSWindow setAlphaValue:1.0];



NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:nil

                                                                     pixelsWide:200

                                                                     pixelsHigh:200

                                                                  bitsPerSample:8

                                                                samplesPerPixel:4

                                                                       hasAlpha:YES

                                                                       isPlanar:NO

                                                                 colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace

                                                                bitmapFormat:NSAlphaNonpremultipliedBitmapFormat

                                                                    bytesPerRow:(200*4)

                                                                   bitsPerPixel:32];



memcpy(imageRep.bitmapData,m_paintBuffer.data,160000);

NSSize imageSize = NSMakeSize(200,200);

NSImage* myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: imageSize];

[myImage addRepresentation:imageRep];

[g_imageView setImage:myImage];
```

where `m_paintBuffer.data` points to the raw pixel data for the image.
Not sure if it is relevant to the question, but m_paintBuffer is of type Mat from OpenCV

Comment: Your window's alpha value is 100% (1.0), so try setting it to 80% `[m_NSWindow setAlphaValue:0.8];`...

Comment: Oh no, but that'll will set that constant alpha value for all the pixels. Although, right now, I am using a constant alpha value, I would eventually want a per-pixel alpha value to be used.

Comment: Your example shows it for the entire window, so if you want it on the image itself then set alpha there.

Comment: It does, but, this is just a representative example to make it easier to explain the problem, which is, to display bitmaps with an alpha channel. Right now, through my example, it appears as if the alpha channel is not being used the way it was intended (as transparency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window's content view is not the entirety of the window's content, as it were. Even a borderless window has (private) theme views surrounding and containing the content view.

In particular, the window has a background color of a light gray. This is drawn "behind" your content view and is opaque. However, you can change it by setting the window's `backgroundColor` property to, for example, `[NSColor clearColor]`. And that's what you should do to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: Coming from a windows background, i didn't think of existence of theme views. Setting it to clearColor was the missing part, indeed.